# CSS :hover breaks button styling in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

The default styling for buttons in IE11 includes a hover effect - the buttons are highlighted in cyan on hover (the exact effect may be theme dependent).  However, adding a seemingly unrelated CSS rule using the `:hover` pseudo-class breaks the hover highlighting on the buttons, and they also exhibit some strange behavior when clicking (the hover highlight seems to be applied and get stuck when clicking the button).

I have a simple test case in JSFiddle, with only the following HTML, which works as expected:

```
<div>
    <button>Prev</button>
    <button>Next</button>
</div>
```

This looks like this when hovering over the "Prev" button:

[image: IE11 button hover effect]

https://jsfiddle.net/qtsfokmy/

If I add the following CSS rule (it doesn't matter what class name is used, or if it is empty or actually does something), the buttons aren't highlighted on hover anymore, but if I click a button the hover effect seems to get stuck (i.e. the button is still highlighted when not hovered after clicking):

```
.AnythingYouWant:hover {}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vwhurLy4/

My PC details are: Windows 7 64-bit SP1, IE11 11.0.9600.18230, Aero Theme

Am I doing something invalid with the CSS to cause this, or is this just an odd IE11 bug?  Is there any way to fix this?  Firefox and Chrome don't seem to be bothered by the `:hover` CSS rule.

Comment: Seems to work for me in IE11: https://jsfiddle.net/vwhurLy4/1/ Can you clarify what problem you're having, and share the actual code used to experience it?

Comment: FYI this only happens when you have an aero theme; it doesn't happen with basic themes (and presumably not with Windows 10).  I couldn't reproduce it until I switched themes.

Comment: Yea that's definitely a bug. I'd submit it.

Comment: Can confirm.  Happens for me in IE 11 on Win 7 but not on IE 11 on Win 10

Comment: @PaulAbbott Thanks for the clarification that this only impacts the aero theme - I didn't think to try a different theme.

Comment: @ChrisW. I don't think they'll be fixing any non-security/non-critical bugs in IE11 at this point. At least that's the responses I've received for bugs I've filed in the past year.

Comment: @TylerH this is true, they have something new coming anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone - I think I have found a work-around in my answer below... if anyone can confirm it works for them them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wondered if there was a way to re-apply the default hover styling to the buttons, but it seems that you don't even need to go that far.  Any non-empty `button:hover` rule seems to fix the default styling (an empty rule *does not* fix the issue), e.g. this rule doesn't actually change anything, but restores the default hover effect in IE11:

```
.AnythingYouWant:hover {}
button:hover {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a better "do nothing" CSS rule to use.  Here's a fiddle showing the "fix" in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/xkf5fbLd/

Comment: Yep, works for me on IE v11.0.9600.18204 on Win7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit, with Aero on.